# Mysql STRICT_MODE disabled on server side but still returning error from DBeaver

Tags: mysql, sql, dbeaver

I have a mysql server with strict mode disabled and when I try to enter invalid value to ENUM column then it inserts empty strings in it which is as expected. But when I try the same with DBeaver it throws error:

```
Data truncated for column 'column_name' at row 1
```

what can be the reason for this. I suppose this might be due to some driver property but not sure which one. I tried enabling & disabling strictUpdates driver properties but both cases are giving error.
Can anyone pointout which property could be different on DBeaver which is checking strictly though mysql server STRICT_MODE is disabled.

Comment: why do you have faulty values in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

In case you have not found out why yet, apparently this is done to force a JDBC compliance check.

Here are my reference posts -

- https://dbeaver.io/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1716
- https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=23371

Posting as I just faced the issue.

This is also probably because DBeaver may have been using older drivers.  I tried the same with Workbench and got correct values.

Hope this helps.